# Get last 6 months first day in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table by a date, in the field LOAD_DATE.
I need to extract the last 6 partitions for the first day of each month.

i.e.
2022-01-01
2021-12-01
2021-11-01
2021-10-01
2021-09-01
2021-08-01

So far, I have something like this, which is pretty ugly, because I have to copy-paste a line to allow more months:

```
SELECT *
FROM partitionedTable
where FECHA_CARGA IN (
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH)
              UNION ALL 
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH)
              UNION ALL 
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 2 MONTH), MONTH),
              UNION ALL 
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 MONTH), MONTH),
              UNION ALL 
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 4 MONTH), MONTH),
              UNION ALL 
              Select 
              DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 5 MONTH), MONTH)
)
```

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change your where clause to

```
fecha_carga in UNNEST(generate_date_array(  date_trunc(date_sub(current_date(), INTERVAL 5 MONTH), MONTH), current_date() , INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: But that is like fecha_carga>=2021-08-01  (using 2022-01-31 as current_date). In other words, the query will bring more than just the six needed dates ¿Or not?

Comment: are the partitions by the first day of the month, meaning between 8/01/2021 and today there are 6 partitions, or does each day have a partition meaning ~180 partitions?

Comment: see the updated